# Does Windows Phone 7 support the Devices Profile for Web Services?

Tags: wcf, web-services, windows-phone-7

Is [DPWS (Devices Profile for Web Services)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms996400.aspx) supported by windows phone 7?

Comment: Department of public works? Double Penetration With Sausages?

Comment: DPWS = Devices Profile for Web Services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the linked document, No.

The protocol starts with a UDP process (for sending the probe message for device discovery) which is not supported on WP7.